# Team Foundation Server: Combine multiple build steps into one step

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

We have many TFS builds in place. I have same set of steps used in many builds. I want to combine them into a single step. So that I can reuse it across the builds instead of repeating each step in each build. Because it is difficult when I have to make changes to the power-shell scripts which need to be changed everywhere.

[image: combine multiple build steps into one]

Answer (score 1):

- If you are use TFS 2017, you can use [**Task Groups**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/task-groups). Press ctrl key -> select the tasks you want to encapsulate -> right click -> create task group. After that, if you need these tasks in another build definition, you can select the task group instead.

  [image]
- If you use other older TFS versions, task groups is not available. But you can **clone a build definition**, then the new build definition will have the tasks and setting with the one you cloned.

  [image]

Comment: Oh that sounds cool. Unfortunately we are on TFS 2015. But problem with  cloning is, if I want to make change in one step then I have to go and do it in every build.

Comment: It would be great if they can allow organization level build steps so I could deploy custom build steps on to my TFS server and reuse them across builds.

Comment: No, TFS 2015 is not support that.